# How to create a method that can fill several comboboxes one at a time?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, ado.net, lookup-tables

I am making an windows form application in C#. In the application, I have a page named category page in which categories are inserted. I wanted to use the categories in another page. So I wrote a method called `fillCombo()` which generate the inserted categories in combo box in another page. Now I have another combo box in that page and I want the same functionality for that also. How can I do that? Can I make a variable of combo box which will be passed in the method? What is the solution for this problem?

```cs
private void fillCombo()
{
    Con.Open(); 
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select CatName from CategoryTbl", Con);
    SqlDataReader rdr;
    rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("CatName", typeof(string));
    dt.Load(rdr);
    CatCb.ValueMember = "catName";
    CatCb.DataSource = dt;
    Con.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can pass the control as a method parameter like that:

```
private void FillComboBox(ComboBox combobox)
{
  if ( combobox == null ) return; // Or throw new Exception...
  Con.Open();
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select CatName from CategoryTbl", Con);
  SqlDataReader rdr;
  rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Columns.Add("CatName", typeof(string));
  dt.Load(rdr);
  combobox.ValueMember = "catName";
  combobox.DataSource = dt;
  Con.Close();
}
```

That we call this way:

```
FillComboBox(myComboBox);
```

Thus we can fill any combo we want, having its own DataSource to its own DataTable, from the logic of the code provided.

It may be improved and refactored to not execute the query and create a table for each combo:

```
private const string CategoryColumnName = "CatName";

private DataTable CategoryLookupTable = new DataTable();

private void InitializeCategoryLookupTable()
{
  if ( Connection == null ) return; // Or throw new Exception...
  Connection.Open();
  try
  {
    using ( var command = new SqlCommand("select CatName from CategoryTbl", Connection) )
    using ( var reader = command.ExecuteReader() )
    {
      CategoryLookupTable.Columns.Add(CategoryColumnName, typeof(string));
      CategoryLookupTable.Load(reader);
    }
  }
  finally
  {
    Connection.Close();
  }
}

private void FillFromCategoryLookupTable(ComboBox combobox)
{
  if ( combobox == null ) return; // Or throw new Exception...
  if ( combobox.DataSource == CategoryLookupTable ) return;
  combobox.DataSource = null;
  combobox.ValueMember = CategoryColumnName;
  combobox.DataSource = CategoryLookupTable;
}
```

Therefore we will call `InitializeCategoryLookupTable` somewhere (in the Form Load or Shown event handler for example) and before any call to `FillFromCategoryLookupTable` :

```
private void MyForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  InitializeCategoryLookupTable();
  FillFromCategoryLookupTable(myFirstComboBox);
}
```

If different source and column name is needed, the refactoring can be done the same manner by passing them as parameters:

```
private DataTable CreateLookupTable(string nameTable, string nameColumn)
{
  if ( Connection == null ) return null;
  Connection.Open();
  try
  {
    using ( var command = new SqlCommand($"select {nameColumn} from {nameTable}", Connection) )
    using ( var reader = command.ExecuteReader() )
    {
      var table = new DataTable();
      table.Columns.Add(nameColumn, typeof(string));
      table.Load(reader);
      return table;
    }
  }
  finally
  {
    Connection.Close();
  }
}

private void FillFromLookupTable(ComboBox combobox, DataTable table, string column)
{
  ...
}
```